# When copying data to Excel Powerpivot, the decimal separators disappear

Tags: excel, powerpivot, vba

I am using Microsoft Office 2013, version 15.0.4753.1003 (it's on my work computer) and I have a problem with Excel. I have a large dataset in an Excel worksheet with sales data that I manually update every month. However, I am almost at the limit of the sheet (a little over 1 million rows).

That is why I have decided to copy the data to Powerpivot, since that tool does not have row limits. I have copied the data to the powerpivot in chunks of 100.000 rows, using Paste and Paste Append. That works fine, except that my decimal seperator vanishes in thin air.

This is a very simplified version of what the data looks like:

```
Product  |   Revenue
Camera   |   299.99
Battery  |   30.00
```

After copying the data to powerpivot it looks like this:

```
Product  |   Revenue
Camera   |   29999
Battery  |   30
```

Something goes wrong with the decimal seperator. My keyboard settings are set on Unites Stated, so a period is the right seperator. I have tried replacing the period by a comma, but then it pastes the data as text instead of numbers. I am, however, in the Netherlands, so officially we use comma seperators. However, since I use many csv reports that use commas as delimiters, I have switched to US settings.

What am I doing wrong with the powerpivot? I don't think it's the location settings, because it does see that `30.00` is 30 and not 3000. Is this a bug in Excel?

Thanks in advance for thinking along!

PS. I know using an actual database serverwould be better, but I don't have the resources to do that in the near future and I just need a quick fix for this specific problem.

PPS. I don't know VBA, so if the solution requires this, I would need very specific instructions.

Comment: Could it be that Powerpivot does not recognize . as a decimal separator?, did you try to replace a .(dot) with a ,(comma) to see if it would work then and if so do a mass replace before transfering the data

Comment: I did try that. I replaced the . with a , before copying the data, but it would paste the data as text instead of numbers. If I manually create a new column in the powerpivot that I assign the value: `=[Revenue]/10` it returns numbers that use a period/dot (.) as a separator, so the dot is the right separator.

Comment: What are the language settings for Power Pivot?

Comment: Why don't you use a DB server instead such as [MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/windows/), [MS SQL](https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=42299), [Teradata](http://downloads.teradata.com/download/database), or any other free DB server. All of them can easily cope with several million rows. Transferring data to and from Excel is quite easy with ADO and VBA. Just do a [Google search](https://www.google.co.uk/#q=excel+vba+ado+update+sql).

Comment: As far as I can tell there is no row limit in Office 365. There is merely a file size limit for Office 365 which you will probably (depending on how many columns you have) hit before exceeding any row limits: https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/Data-Model-specification-and-limits-19aa79f8-e6e8-45a8-9be2-b58778fd68ef?CorrelationId=05df35c5-30d5-447f-82dd-40f72f84e482&ui=en-US&rs=en-GB&ad=GB

Comment: @Ralph I have tested and there is a row limit. I cannot have more than 1,048,576 rows. 

I cannot run free databases, because I am using a work computer and don't have administrator rights. I have tried in the past to get this, but I wasn't granted permission. In the long run, the data will be entered in a data cube, but it is currently not the top priority of our Business Intelligence department.

Comment: @Rory: The language settings for Powerpivot are as follows:
`Language Options: Match Excel Language,
Current Language: English (United States),
Model Language: Dutch (Netherlands)`

Comment: I think that last one is the cause of your problems. Does your computer have its Regional settings (not just keyboard) set to Dutch, or US, locale?

Comment: @Rory I went to language and region setting. I changed format from Dutch (in the additional settings I had specified the dot as a decimal separator) to English (United Stated). I set the current location to the US instead of NL. And I changed keyboard settings from `Dutch (United States International)` to `English (United States International)`. Somehow, one of these changes solved the problem. It's weird that this is the first time Excel made a problem out of this. Still, it works now. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @Ralph, the linked article is discussing limitations on the amount of data in the Excel Data Model, which is an alternate name for Power Pivot. The number of rows in a worksheet page is still limited to ~1M.

Answer (score -1):

Go to control panel, click on **Region**, go to **Additional settings** and change your digit grouping and decimal symbol.